# Python generator to evenly split (for parallelizing) iteration over an upper triangular matrix

Tags: python, optimization, generator

I use the following code to iterate over the upper triangular portion of a matrix in parallel, but I would prefer to do this without instantiating the entire set of index pairs.

The goal is to process all items in the upper triangular portion of the matrix, but to parallelize that processing. Also note that I'm fine using 3rd party libraries (numpy, etc.) if they have some tool to help with this.

```
n_processes = 4
n = 1000  # num cols/rows in matrix
pairs = [(i, j) for i, j in itertools.combinations(xrange(n), 2)]
per_chunk = int(round(len(pairs) / float(n_processes)))
pair_chunks = [pairs[i*per_chunk:i*per_chunk+per_chunk] for i in xrange(n_processes)]
p = multiprocessing.Process(target=process_pairs, args=pair_chunks[0])
p = multiprocessing.Process(target=process_pairs, args=pair_chunks[1])
p = multiprocessing.Process(target=process_pairs, args=pair_chunks[2])
p = multiprocessing.Process(target=process_pairs, args=pair_chunks[3])
def process_pairs(cur_pairs):
    for i, j in pairs:
        # do some stuff
```

Any clever thoughts on representing this as a generator (i.e., without generating all the index pairs)?  As is, pairs needs to be loaded into memory, and if *n* is very large, that's a hit to memory I'd like to avoid.

Comment: Please clarify your question, it is rather unclear what `pair_chunks` are precisely. Posting an example, with the desired output would help.

Comment: I updated my question with further clarification of how the chunked pairs are used. For those downvoting, hopefully these updates fix your concerns, otherwise please explain why not.

Comment: What's the problem with the above code?

Comment: @StefanPochmann -- If n is very large, a decent amount of memory is used, and I'm trying to optimize memory usage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps something like that (converted to Python 3):

```
from itertools import combinations_with_replacement, islice, tee

n_processes = 3
n = 10  # num cols/rows in matrix

pairs = ((i, j) for i, j in combinations_with_replacement(range(n), 2) if i != j)
pair_chunks = [
  islice(p, i, None, n_processes)
  for i, p in enumerate(tee(pairs, n_processes))
]

print(pair_chunks)
print([list(x) for x in pair_chunks])
```

Output:

```
[<itertools.islice object at 0x7f2149fbe138>, <itertools.islice object at 0x7f2149fbecc8>, <itertools.islice object at 0x7f2149fbe228>]
[[(0, 1), (0, 4), (0, 7), (1, 2), (1, 5), (1, 8), (2, 4), (2, 7), (3, 4), (3, 7), (4, 5), (4, 8), (5, 7), (6, 7), (7, 8)], [(0, 2), (0, 5), (0, 8), (1, 3), (1, 6), (1, 9), (2, 5), (2, 8), (3, 5), (3, 8), (4, 6), (4, 9), (5, 8), (6, 8), (7, 9)], [(0, 3), (0, 6), (0, 9), (1, 4), (1, 7), (2, 3), (2, 6), (2, 9), (3, 6), (3, 9), (4, 7), (5, 6), (5, 9), (6, 9), (8, 9)]]
```

This copies the generator using `tee` and then creates a new generator using `islice` that is starting from a different position, each moving n_processes steps forward.

Or the complete example using processes:

```
from multiprocessing import Process
from itertools import combinations_with_replacement, islice, tee

n_processes = 3
n = 10  # num cols/rows in matrix

pairs = ((i, j) for i, j in combinations_with_replacement(range(n), 2) if i != j)
pair_chunks = [
    islice(p, i, None, n_processes)
    for i, p in enumerate(tee(pairs, n_processes))
]

def process_pairs(i, pair_chunk):
    print('process %d received type %s' % (i, type(pair_chunk)))
    for x in pair_chunk:
        print('process %d processing %s' % (i, x))

processes = [
    Process(target=process_pairs, args=[i, pair_chunk])
    for i, pair_chunk in enumerate(pair_chunks)
]
for p in processes:
    p.start()

for p in processes:
    p.join()
```

Output:

```
process 0 received type <class 'itertools.islice'>
process 1 received type <class 'itertools.islice'>
process 1 processing (0, 2)
process 1 processing (0, 5)
process 1 processing (0, 8)
process 1 processing (1, 3)
process 1 processing (1, 6)
process 1 processing (1, 9)
process 1 processing (2, 5)
process 1 processing (2, 8)
process 1 processing (3, 5)
process 0 processing (0, 1)
...
```

Comment: Great answer, it solves the issue, but there is a memory issue, seems that because of the itertools usage, if the matrix is big the ram will be overloaded. I am triying to find exactry why, and how to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

Presumably, if you don't want the indices, the generator will need to return the values directly.

Likewise, it sound likes you're not wanting to flatten the upper triangle, so the row vectors need to be kept distinct.

With those a presumptive requirements, here is a generator that yields the successive slices of row vectors:

```
>>> def generate_upper_triangular(m):
        for i, row in enumerate(m):
            yield row[i:]

>>> m = [[1, 2, 3],
         [0, 5, 6],
         [0, 0, 9]]
>>> for vec in generate_upper_triangular(m):
        print(vec)

[1, 2, 3]
[5, 6]
[9]
```

Comment: @Stefan I'm trying to infer his actual requirements from the text of the question.  Otherwise, it isn't clear to me what he/she really wants.

Comment: @RaymondHettinger -- I updated my question to clarify how the pair chunks are used. I don't think your current code would do what I need. Let me know if question/usage still unclear. Thanks!